# How to solve "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" when updating using LINQ to SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I encountered this exception when I was updating a record.
I have 2 tables, digital_material and material.
The digital_material has a foreign key to the material table in material_id.
I was trying to update a record which already has a value assigned to it. 
Here's the code.

```
Dim query = from data in _db.digital_material where data.material_id.equals(txt) select data
with query.single
    .material_id = new_material_id
    'other update syntax. The one that got caught was the first one.
end with
```

And after the code passed through that line, the exception appeared.
I read that in C#, this problem can be solved by changing the association property and not the foreign keys. Is it the same with VB.NET? And if yes, how do I do it? If not, is there any way to solve this?
This is a strange one because I usually use the usual LINQ command and never encountered this exception before. Thank you for reading and for the help!

Comment: Just some thoughts...Are you violating a key constraint? Or do you need to lock the row before changing the value?

Comment: Nope. I also don't need to lock the row before changing. I always use this, but suddenly this exception appeared.

Comment: Any updates to the server that you aren't aware of?  Whenever I see "state" I always think connection state open/closed or the locked records I mentioned first.  Is there an error code as well and what's actually throwing the error? SQL server?  App server?